# batch loop until condition is satisfied

Tags: loops, batch-file

I am using windows , and I want to do a loop inside a bat and to break it when a condition is satisfied , and I dont want to use **goto** , can some one give me the general way to do it ?
in my case , I want to loop until a file size is bigger than 200 KB , so in my batch I create a file (that's get bigger with time) , then I want to check it size with loop
if it greater than 200 KB I want to break loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the batch scripting language doesn't have `while` loops, only `for` loops with a predetermined amount of iterations, so I'm afraid that `if`+`goto` is your only option. Why are you determined to avoid `goto` statements in batch?

The following code resembles a common `do-while` loop:

```
:do_while_loop_start
rem This is the body of the loop (do something here...)

:do_while_loop_end
for /f "usebackq" %%a in ('somefile.txt') do set filesize=%%~za
if %filesize% leq 204800 goto do_while_loop_start
```

Isn't it elegant enough? I think it is.

Comment: thank you for the solution, for the goto , i think goto loop is slower than other loops , and because my professor of the C language told us that goto is evil :) at least in c .

Comment: In general, `goto` is evil, because it can break control flow (for instance, you can jump from an `if` into an `else` of another if). However, sometimes _in batch_ you cannot do without it. In these cases I guess it's okay to use it.